# Stop HTML Entites

Tags: html, wordpress

Is there a way to stop a HTML entity from being rendered?

By that I mean that I'd like to have 2 lines. First is where the entity is rendered (e.g. &), and on the second line, I'd like to have the entity itself but not rendered (e.g. & - amp;).

I don't know if it helps, but I'm using WordPress to add both these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the ampersand. For instance, instead of `&nbsp;` render the ampersand as an entity: `&amp;nbsp;`.

As per your example, use `&amp;amp;`.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought it would've worked including the entity in a <code> tag but it seems not.

Comment: Just put `&amp;amp;` right in the page's HTML. The escape is built-in!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use htmlentities() in php or htmlspecialchars()
wordpress is in php.so you can use those functions like this :
htmlspecialchars('your tags');

Comment: There is no need to involve PHP, see my answer below.